# Updating Django version to 1.10

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm taking over an old project under Django for which I don't know the basic version to use, on my server I have 1.9.9, I tried to build it via docker, but without success...

So I try to migrate Django 1.x to 1.10, but I currently have a problem with model dependency. when I launch the application I get an error message :

***stack trace***

```
web_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1       |   File "./manage.py", line 9, in <module>
web_1       |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
web_1       |     utility.execute()
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
web_1       |     django.setup()
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
web_1       |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
web_1       |     app_config.import_models(all_models)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
web_1       |     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
web_1       |     __import__(name)
web_1       |   File "/usr/src/app/ots/geo/models.py", line 19, in <module>
web_1       |     from ots.otsapi.models import RPCForeignKey
web_1       |   File "/usr/src/app/ots/otsapi/models.py", line 4, in <module>
web_1       |     from .fields import *
web_1       |   File "/usr/src/app/ots/otsapi/fields.py", line 7, in <module>
web_1       |     from django.db.models.fields.subclassing import Creator
web_1       | ImportError: No module named subclassing
```

I don't find the "replacing" dependency of subclassing and Creator.

do you know what I can do to replace that with?

***requirement.txt***

```
-e git://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie.git@da9df5abcfcec1c0a659b179edcdfc0d3465e41c#egg=django-tastypie
-e git://github.com/python-babel/django-babel.git@5d953ef9e38ca5faf0ac4b39c9757aa87a40c00e#egg=django-babel
babel==2.2.0
BeautifulSoup>=3.2.1,<4.0.0
boto>=2.38.0,<3.0.0
cached-property==1.2.0
celery==3.1.23
crispy-forms-foundation==0.2.3.1
django-celery==3.1.17
django==1.10
django-modeltranslation==0.11
django-sortable>=0.3,<0.4
django-cacheback>=1.0,<2.0.0
django-filter==0.14
django-rest-auth>=0.9,<1
django-allauth>=0.24,<30
django-statsd-mozilla>=0.3,<1
drf-extensions>=0.2.8,<1.0.0
enum34>=1.0.4,<2.0.0
fastcache==1.0.2
freezegun==0.1.11
html5lib==0.95
iso8601==0.1.4
isodate==0.5.0
isoweek==1.3.0
kombu==3.0.37
libthumbor==1.0.1
markdown==2.2.1
mimeparse==0.1.3
mysqlclient==1.3.7
nameko==2.1.2
newrelic==2.60.0.46
pillow==2.5.1
purl==1.0
pypdf==1.13
python-cjson==1.0.5
python-dateutil==2.1
python-gettext==2.0
python-memcached==1.57
python-openid==2.2.5
python-updict==0.1.2
pytz==2015.7
raven==3.2.1
reportlab>=3.2.0,<4.0.0
requests>=2.8.1,<3.0.0
six>=1.10.0,<2.0.0
sorl-thumbnail==12.3
sphinx==1.1.3
statsd==1.0.0
tempdir==0.5
ua-parser==0.5.1
universal-analytics-python==0.2.4
user-agents==1.0.1
wsgiref>=0.1.2,<1.0.0
zerorpc==0.5.1
sqlparse>=0.1.18,<1.0.0  # required by extend migration 0003
python-geoip-geolite2==2015.0303
python-geoip-python3==1.3
hasattr-safe>=0.1.0,<1.0.0
django-fancy-cache>=0.8.0,<1.0.0
django-filer>=1.1.1,<2.0.0  # django-cms
cmsplugin-filer>=1.0.1,<2.0.0  # django-cms
django-reversion>=1.10.1,<2.0.0  # django-cms
djangocms-snippet>=1.7.1,<2.0.0  # django-cms
aldryn-newsblog==1.3.0 # django-cms-blog
django-cors-headers==1.2.2
django-oauth-toolkit==0.12.0
```

***fields.py***

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from django import forms
from django.db import models
from django.apps import apps
from django.core import exceptions
from django.db.models.fields.subclassing import Creator


# Mixin
class SortableMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.sortable = kwargs.pop('sortable', False)
        self.sortable_field = kwargs.pop('sortable_field', None)
        super(SortableMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class IntegerField(SortableMixin, models.IntegerField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase


class BooleanField(SortableMixin, models.BooleanField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase


class NullBooleanField(SortableMixin, models.NullBooleanField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase


class TextField(SortableMixin, models.TextField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase


class CharField(SortableMixin, models.CharField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase


class DateTimeField(SortableMixin, models.DateTimeField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase


class TimeField(SortableMixin, models.TimeField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase


class DecimalField(models.DecimalField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase


class FloatField(models.FloatField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase


class StringListField(models.Field):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid_list': 'Attribute should be a list',
    }

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {
            'form_class': forms.CommaSeparatedField,
        }
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(StringListField, self).formfield(**defaults)

    def clean(self, value, model_instance):
        value = self.to_python(value)
        self.validate(value, model_instance)
        for v in value:
            self.run_validators(v)
        return value

    def validate(self, value, model_instance):
        if not isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_list'])
        return super(StringListField, self).validate(value, model_instance)


class LazyLookupFieldCreator(Creator):
    def __init__(self, field):
        self.field = field
        self.cache_name = field.get_cache_name()

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self

        try:
            rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)
        except AttributeError:
            pk = instance.__dict__[self.field.attname]
            if pk:
                args = {
                    self.field._related_pk: pk
                }
                rel_obj = self.field._related_model_class.objects.get(**args)
            else:
                rel_obj = None
            setattr(instance, self.cache_name, rel_obj)

        return rel_obj

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        setattr(instance, self.cache_name, value)
        pk = getattr(value, self.field._related_pk)
        instance.__dict__[self.field.attname] = pk


class LazyLookupFieldMeta(models.SubfieldBase):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
            models.Field.contribute_to_class(self, cls, name)
            setattr(cls, self.name, LazyLookupFieldCreator(self))

        new_class = super(LazyLookupFieldMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        new_class.contribute_to_class = contribute_to_class
        return new_class


class LazyLookupField(models.Field):
    __metaclass__ = LazyLookupFieldMeta

    def __init__(self, related_field, related_model_class, pk="pk", *args, **kwargs):
        self._related_field = related_field
        self._related_model_class = self.get_related_model_class(related_model_class)
        self._related_pk = pk
        return super(LazyLookupField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super(LazyLookupField, self).deconstruct()
        if self._related_field:
            kwargs['related_field'] = self._related_field
        if self._related_model_class:
            kwargs['related_model_class'] = self._related_model_class
        return name, path, args, kwargs

    def get_related_model_class(self, related_model_class):
        if not isinstance(related_model_class, basestring):
            return related_model_class

        if related_model_class == 'self':
            return

        try:
            app, model = related_model_class.split('.')
        except ValueError:
            return

        return apps.get_model(app, model)

    def get_attname(self):
        return self._related_field

    def get_attname_column(self):
        attname = self.get_attname()
        return attname, attname


class PlatformModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    """
    A simple ModelChoiceField that assumes an integer based id
    """
    def clean(self, value):
        try:
            value = int(value)
            value = self.queryset.get(id=value)
        except (ValueError, self.queryset.model.DoesNotExist):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid value supplied: {}'.format(value))
        return value


class SimpleModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    """
    A simple ModelChoiceField that assumes an integer based id
    """
    def clean(self, value):
        if value:
            return value
        return None


class ReverseLazyLookupFieldCreator(Creator):
    def __init__(self, field):
        self.field = field
        self.cache_name = field.get_cache_name()

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None:
            raise AttributeError('Can only be accessed via instance')

        try:
            value = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)
        except AttributeError:
            instance_value = getattr(instance, self.field.to_field, None)

            model = self.field.get_related_model_class()
            field_name = self.field.field_name

            if instance_value:
                try:
                    value = model.objects.get(**{
                        field_name: instance_value
                    })
                except model.DoesNotExist:
                    if self.field.null:
                        value = None
                    else:
                        raise
                setattr(instance, self.cache_name, value)
        return value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        setattr(instance, self.cache_name, value)


class ReverseLazyLookupFieldMeta(models.SubfieldBase):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
            self.set_attributes_from_name(name)
            self.model = cls
            cls._meta.add_field(self, virtual=True)
            setattr(cls, self.name, ReverseLazyLookupFieldCreator(self))
        new_class = super(ReverseLazyLookupFieldMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        new_class.contribute_to_class = contribute_to_class
        return new_class


class ReverseLazyLookupField(models.Field):
    __metaclass__ = ReverseLazyLookupFieldMeta

    def __init__(self, related_model, field_name, to_field='pk', **kwargs):
        self.related_model = related_model
        self.field_name = field_name
        self.to_field = to_field
        kwargs['editable'] = False
        super(ReverseLazyLookupField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_related_model_class(self):
        if not isinstance(self.related_model, basestring):
            return self.related_model

        if self.related_model == 'self':
            return

        try:
            app, model = self.related_model.split('.')
        except ValueError:
            return

        return apps.get_model(app, model)

    def get_attname(self):
        return self.name

    def get_attname_column(self):
        attname = self.get_attname()
        return attname, None


class RPCForeignKeyCreator(Creator):
    def __init__(self, field):
        self.field = field
        self.cache_name = field.get_cache_name()

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self

        model_class = self.field.get_related_model_class()

        try:
            rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)
        except AttributeError:
            pk = instance.__dict__[self.field.attname]
            if pk is None and self.field.null:
                return None
            args = {
                'pk': pk
            }
            rel_obj = getattr(model_class, self.field.manager_attr).get(**args)
            setattr(instance, self.cache_name, rel_obj)

        if rel_obj is None:
            raise model_class.DoesNotExist()

        return rel_obj

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value is None:
            instance.__dict__[self.field.attname] = None
            return
        setattr(instance, self.cache_name, value)
        pk = getattr(value, 'pk')
        instance.__dict__[self.field.attname] = pk


class RPCForeignKeyMeta(models.SubfieldBase):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
            models.Field.contribute_to_class(self, cls, name)
            setattr(cls, self.name, RPCForeignKeyCreator(self))

        new_class = super(RPCForeignKeyMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        new_class.contribute_to_class = contribute_to_class
        return new_class


class RPCForeignKey(models.IntegerField):
    __metaclass__ = RPCForeignKeyMeta

    def __init__(self, related_model, manager_attr='objects', **kwargs):
        self.related_model = related_model
        self.manager_attr = manager_attr
        super(RPCForeignKey, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_related_model_class(self):
        if not isinstance(self.related_model, basestring):
            return self.related_model

        if self.related_model == 'self':
            return

        try:
            app, model = self.related_model.split('.')
        except ValueError:
            return

        return apps.get_model(app, model)

    def get_attname(self):
        return '%s_id' % self.name

    def south_field_triple(self):
        from south.modelsinspector import introspector
        args, kwargs = introspector(self)

        #  We set these as None because they have no impact on the database,
        # and real values confuse South
        kwargs['related_model'] = None
        kwargs['manager_attr'] = None

        return (
            'ots.otsapi.fields.RPCForeignKey',
            args,
            kwargs,
        )

    def deconstruct(self):
        model_class_path = 'ots.otsapi.fields.RPCForeignKey'
        name, path, args, kwargs = super(RPCForeignKey, self).deconstruct()
        kwargs['related_model'] = None
        kwargs['manager_attr'] = None
        return name, model_class_path, args, kwargs
```

Comment: The subclassing was removed: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-10

Comment: See for more details the release notes of 1.8: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/#subfieldbase

Comment: Can you share your `/usr/src/app/ots/otsapi/fields.py` file (well at least the parts where you use the `Creator` as a superclass)?

Comment: Yep it's available here : [https://pastebin.com/raw/7GV4HGFw](https://pastebin.com/raw/7GV4HGFw)